# String Array type method return type error

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
public String[][] GetAllItems() 
    {
        FoodCityData.ShoppingBuddyEntities fdContext = new FoodCityData.ShoppingBuddyEntities();

        IQueryable<Item> Query =
       from c in fdContext.Item
       select c;

        List<Item> AllfNames = Query.ToList();
        int arrayZise = AllfNames.Count;
        String[,] xx = new String[arrayZise,2];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        foreach(Item x in AllfNames)
        {

                xx[i,0] = x.ItemName.ToString();
                xx[i, 1] = x.ItemPrice.ToString();
                i++;

        }

        return xx[2,2];  // how do i write return type?
    }
```

Im gettin an error in this code segment return type. Can i know how to write this method correct way?

Comment: which error ? post it here

Comment: how on earth do you expect us to help you if you don't provide the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [Jagged Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) return type and you need to return two dimensional [Rrectangular Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), You can return two dimensional array like this.

```
public String[,] GetAllItems() 
{
    //your code 
    String[,] xx = new String[arrayZise,2];
    //your code 
    return xx;    
}
```

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot serialize object of type System.String[,]. Multidimensional arrays are not supported. 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize object of type System.String[,]. Multidimensional arrays are not supported.


Im running a web service and it says it does not allow to do such thigs? can you help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is suppose to return [Jagged Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) where as you are trying to return [Multidimensional Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Modify your method signature as:

```
public String[,] GetAllItems()
```

Currently your method is returning a single string and that is why the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `string` but your return type is a `string[][]`. I think what you want to do is return a `string[,]`:

```
public string[,] GetAllItems() 
{
    ...
    return xx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method return types is *[jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)* and since your `xx[2,2]` is a `string`, your method returns simple `string`, that's why you are getting an error.

Just return *[two diamensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)* like;

```
public String[,] GetAllItems() 
{
  .....
  return xx[2,2];    
}
```